# Lost email when pressing ctrl+shift+m in Thunderbird

Tags: email, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, inbox

I was in my `inbox` in Thunderbird. I accidentally pressed the combination of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and the selected email just disappeared.

In this Thunderbird shourcut documentation: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts, I can see that the key combination means:

> Move/Copy message to previous target folder Again

But there is not a "previous target folder" in my mind previous to `inbox`.

## Question:

Where should I look for my lost email?

Thnx.